# Storing user input in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

What i have to create is a form that i migrated out of access. I created the 4 asp pages. Now what they would like is to store the user input values some how until they hit the final page before writing to the SQL database. What is the easiest way to store this data until the final page for submission? I could try an array or maybe even java script?

Comment: JavaScript is the most unreliable way. Session or hidden form input are both common and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the session object - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525095(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638503/447356), you could use session variables.  The alternative is to just pass them from page to page using hidden form fields, eg

```
<input name="yourvariable" type="hidden" value="<%=Request.Form("yourvariable")%>
```

There's no correct answer, it's a case of which you're most comfortable with

Answer (score 0):

"get_user_info.asp"

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id='frm_user_info' name='frm_user_info' method='post' action='get_user_info_go.asp'>
<table cellspacing='3'>
<tr>
<td align=right>Name</td>
<td><input type='text' id='s_name' name='s_name' size='40'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' value='Next'></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

"get_user_info_go.asp"

```
<%
s_name=request.form("s_name")
if (s_name="") then response.redirect("get_user_info.asp")
session("s_name")=s_name
response.redirect("next_page.asp")
%>
```